# C++ Boost Max Deviation

Tags: c++, boost

Little bit of a brain teaser, I'm wondering if there is a simple way using Boost to get the max deviation of a value from the mean using an accumulator_set? Just the furthest point from the mean.

Values are in a `accumulator_set<float, stats<tag::variance>> val` though I suspect other tags might be needed.

```
// defined by: MAX(abs(val[x] - mean)) 
float max_stdev(accumulator_set<float, stats<tag::variance>>& val) {
  // mean(val) gives mean

  // can't just use max on the set 
}

// e.g. val contains 1,2,3
accumulator_set<float, stats<tag::variance>> val
val(1), val(2), val(3);
float max_val = max_stdev(val);  // would return 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum deviation is either the maximum value minus the mean or the mean minus the minimum, whichever is greater. This suggests the following simple implementation:

```
double max_deviation(accumulator_set<double, features<tag::min, tag::max, tag::mean> > const &acc) {
  return std::max(max(acc) - mean(acc), mean(acc) - min(acc));
}
```

Comment: ahh, that is exactly how to think about the problem. Solid answer.